# Wordpress drop domain alias

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, urls

my client try to change domain without me and now, when you try to go into http://klenotnictvi-benesov.cz it will change into this site http://davidpros/
I can not change it in wordpress admin. So can somebody tell me how to change it in files? I can connect into server by FTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are **NOT** using **WordPress MultiSite** add the following in wp-config.php.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://klenotnictvi-benesov.cz' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://klenotnictvi-benesov.cz' );
```

If you **ARE** using **WordPress MultiSite** you will need to access the database directly and edit the wp_options table and change "siteurl" & "home" to the correct url.

Here is more info on [changing the site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: I'd also check the htaccess file for proper values.

Comment: thats a good idea!

Comment: ...although I never like to change it in the wp-config.php file; I'd rather set it properly in the wp-options table. And make sure my htaccess file is according to suggestions in the Codex.